# Copy files that have at least the mention of one certain word

Tags: bash, shell, loops, if-statement, grep

I want to look through 100K+ text files from a directory and copy to another directory only the ones which contain at least one word from a list.

I tried doing an if statement with grep and cp but I have no idea how to make it to work this way.

```
for filename in *.txt 
do 
grep -o -i "cultiv" "protec" "agricult" $filename|wc -w 
if [ wc -gt 0 ]
then cp $filename ~/desktop/filepath
fi 
done
```

Obviously this does not work but I have no idea how to store the wc result and then compare it to 0 and only act on those files.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-l` option to have `grep` print all the filenames that match the pattern. Then use `xargs` to pass these as arguments to `cp`.

```
grep -l -E -i 'cultiv|protec|agricult' *.txt | xargs cp -t ~/desktop/filepath --
```

The `-t` option is a GNU `cp` extension, it allows you to put the destination directory first so that it will work with `xargs`.

If you're using a version without that option, you need to use the `-J` option to `xargs` to substitute in the middle of the command.

```
grep -l -E -i 'cultiv|protec|agricult' *.txt | xargs -J {} cp -- {} ~/desktop/filepath
```

Comment: thank you very much! I managed to make it work but it does not copy the files, instead it gives me: usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory

Comment: What OS are you using? The `-t` option is a GNU extension to `cp`.

Comment: I'm on macOS, I figured out that the -t could not be used and I tried without it and it gave me that

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it on MacOS.

Comment: Maybe worth using `--` before the file list too, the error might come from files starting with a dash that `cp` would try to interpret as flags

Comment: Thanks! It's making progress but now the problem is that it copies all the files and not only the ones matching the pattern.

Comment: I don't see how that could happen. `grep -l` only prints the filenames that match.

Comment: I'd never heard of `-J` til I saw this. It doesn't exist in GNU xargs and even after reading the man page on MacOS I can't figure out the difference between `-J` and `-I` (which is available in all xargs). Why use `-J` instead of `-I`?

Comment: @EdMorton I had to play with it to see the difference. `-J` makes it repeat the placeholder as many times as necessary, just like the way the default action appends the arguments at the end. `-I` replaces all the placeholders with the same input value, so it runs the command once for each input.

Comment: OK, got it (I think!). Thanks for the info.